# Making CSS generic for image centering

Tags: javascript, css

Below is my CSS. It is used to centre an image. (This code works)

```
.imagecentre{
    width: 25px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;

}
```

In order for it to work, you need to state the width. However, not all my images are 25px.

How can I make this css generic enough to accommodate all images using javascript?

Comment: Why can't you wrap it up in a `div` and give `text-align: center;`?

Comment: Are you using a library (like jQuery) or vanilla js

Comment: @user1724140, the problem is to center any img? http://jsfiddle.net/znCjW/ -- if i've understood you correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to center an image in a container, you can set `text-align: center` on the container, regardless of what styles you have on the image:

```
<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/2012/vets_day-12-hp.jpg">
</div>​
```

Comment: I changed my html code so I can satisfy your code. Now it works

Comment: @user1724140 I proposed this method first! :|

Comment: Hey @PraveenKumar, I hadn't seen your comment, but hey, here's a +1 from me :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks for commenting too :) Appreciate all the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following structure:

```
.image-wrapper {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.image-wrapper > img {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `margin: 0px auto`, only if the element is block element (div,p,h1 etc..) and not inline elements (images and span for example are inline elements) so you need to add text-align:center; to the parent element of the inline element..)

if it's more than one picture into the div..

```
 img.imagecentre{
        width: 25px;
        display:block;
        float:left;
        margin: 0 10px 0 0; /* change the 10 to the space you want.. */

    }
```

if it's one picture...  (div_warp = the parent div of the image, imagecentre = the img element)..

```
#div_warp {
text-align center;
...
...
}

 .imagecentre{
        width: 25px;   
    }
```

Comment: this is promising.. trying it out

Answer (score 0):

In the jquery set the widht dynamically to `".imagecentre"` class

```
$(function(){
    $(".imagecentre").css("width", $(this).width());
});
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: I am still a new to css, but wouldnt this effect all images, cos it is a class? Basically if I set the width to 30px, all images will be set to that width? Is this the case? Sorry if its a dumb question

Comment: In this case the width will be calculated dynamically according to the width of img on which ".imagecenter" class specified. Also dont forget to remove the width attribute from this class